# Spring 3 MVC Web services: many parameters with same name

Tags: web-services, spring, spring-mvc, parameter-passing, spring-3

I am running into the next problem. I have declared a method in the controller like the next one, to be used as a web service:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/" + "prueba" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void prueba(ExampleBean pExample1, ExamlpleBean pExample2) {
    // Wonderful code here

}
```

And the class ExampleBean is just, well, a Bean:

```
public class ExampleBean implements Serializable {

   private String id;
   private String whatever;

   // getters, setters, and more.
}
```

If the interface were something like that:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/" + "prueba" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void prueba(ExampleBean pExample1) {
    // Wonderful code here

}
```

Each time I would like to call that web service, I would call the URL in the next way:

http://myWebProject/prueba?id=1&whatever=hola

But... How can I do when I have to give values to both params from the same class? I mean, I can not repeat parameters, so I dont know how to differ between the id from pExample1, and the id from pExample2 when writing the URL.

I mean, also with two parameters from different classes, but with an attribute with the same name. For example, if the second parameter is from the class DifferentExampleBean, which has also an "id" parameter.

Thanks a lot!

PS: I am using StringHttpMessageConverter.

Comment: can you use varargs? `prueba(ExampleBean... exampleBean)`

Comment: Well... Sorry, maybe I have to reformulate the question. I would like to know how do I do when 2 parameters have the same name. I mean, even if two parameters from differen classes have one attribute with the same name. But thanks for the interest ;-)

Answer (score 1):

What you would do is to create a parent class which would hold particular field you're interested in then both `ExampleBean` and `ExampleBean1` would extend this parent class and you'd have only one type to be sent in `prueba(ParentClass instance1, ParentClass instance2)`.

Where `instance1` would be instance of `ExampleBean` and `instance2` would be instance of `ExampleBean2`

Comment: Sorry, have updated the question. My problem has to do with how to give values to the parameters in the URL. Really sorry for not being able to state it clear :-(

Comment: @Raspayu give the String paremeters in URL i.e. in JSON format, than deserialize it inside the method and do whatever with your instance. I recommend `Google gson`

Comment: Sorry, looks like I have to deal with that as it is :-( But thanks for the recommendation, will look for that for future proyects.